# Update Manager -

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I'm quit new to Ubuntu and i still getting settled.
But i came across an error that's been bugging me.
Can't update

```
Failed to download repository information

Check your Internet connection
```

.

detail:

```
W:Failed to fetch http-://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http-://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http-://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http-://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

I've seen some of this problems around but still can't find out what is wrong :/ (using 12.04 btw)

Any help is really appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The dash after http:// looks weird: `http-://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources`

Also, those PPAs seem to have been removed:

`http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/`

there should be a `precise` directory here but it's empty? I suggest you check with the people who maintain these PPAs for replacements, but it seems to me like they're not working anymore and you should remove them.

This question has good information on how to remove non-working PPAs: [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa) (taken from Jorge's comment).